Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'url' has already been declared
I have used Javascript to access the Google-text-to-speech API for over a year. But suddenly it stopped working getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'url' has already been declared texttospeech.js:1". I don't see any obvious errors. I can see the script is being enqueued for the page correctly, but it does not execute the script due to the syntax error. I added a console.log command to the first line of the script and when I use the Chrome Inspect Tool, nothing shows up in the console other than the uncaught syntax error. Has anyone else run into this? Here is copy of the script, any help would be greatly appreciated.

    console.log("BEFORE!")
    // // Declare a variable to store the access Token
    let accessToken
    
    // Get the current WindowURL.
    const url = window.location.href;let url = window.location.href;
    
    function parseAccessTokenFromUrl(url) {
      // Get the current URL.
      const urlObject = new URL(url);
    
      // Get the hash fragment of the URL.
      const hashFragment = urlObject.hash;
    
      // Remove the leading `#` character from the hash fragment.
      const hashFragmentWithoutHash = hashFragment.substring(1);
    
      // Find the index of the `&token_type` parameter in the hash fragment.
      const tokenTypeIndex = hashFragmentWithoutHash.indexOf('&token_type');
    
      // Extract the substring of the hash fragment from the index of the `#access_token=` sign to the index of the `&token_type` parameter.
      const extractedAccessToken = hashFragmentWithoutHash.substring(hashFragmentWithoutHash.indexOf('#access_token=') + 14, tokenTypeIndex);
    
      // Assign the extracted access token to the global variable
      accessToken = extractedAccessToken;
    
    }
    
    // Get the input variables from the form
    // Get the user-entered text
          
    
    // Console Log the values to be passed
     console.log('Access token:', accessToken);
    
     console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
    
    
     function displaySliderValue(slider) {
      // Get the ID of the slider
      const sliderId = slider.id;
    
      // Display the slider value in the DOM
      if (sliderId === 'pitchSlider') {
        document.getElementById('pitchValue').textContent = slider.value;
      } else if (sliderId === 'speedSlider') {
        document.getElementById('speedValue').textContent = slider.value;
      } else {
        // Handle unknown slider
      }
    }
    
    // Reset the Slider Values to the default Values
    const resetButton = document.getElementById('reset-Button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Get the default pitch and speed values
      const defaultPitchRate = 0;
      const defaultSpeakingRate = 1;
    
      // Set the slider values to the default values
      document.getElementById('pitchSlider').value = defaultPitchRate;
      document.getElementById('speedSlider').value = defaultSpeakingRate;
    
      // Update the slider values in the DOM
      displaySliderValue(document.getElementById('pitchSlider'));
      displaySliderValue(document.getElementById('speedSlider'));
    });
    
    
    const playButton = document.getElementById('play-button');
    playButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      // Play the text
      const text = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
    
      // Get the selected voice language
      const selectedVoice = document.getElementById('voiceSelect').value;
    
      // Get the selected language code
      const selectedLanguage = document.getElementById('languageSelect').value;
    
      // Get the selected pitch value (0-2)
      const pitchRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pitchSlider').value);
    
      // Get the selected speed value (0.25-4)
      const speakingRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('speedSlider').value);
    
    
      console.log('Text input:', text);
      console.log('Selected voice:', selectedVoice);
      console.log('Selected language code:', selectedLanguage);
      console.log('Voice pitch:', pitchRate);
      console.log('Playback speed:', speakingRate);
      
    
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "input": {
              "text": `${text}`
            }, // Enclose the text value in quotes
            "voice": {
              "name": `${selectedVoice}`,
              "languageCode": `${selectedLanguage}`
            }, // Enclose the selectedVoice value in quotes
            "audioConfig": {
              "audioEncoding": "MP3",
              "speakingRate": `${speakingRate}`,
              "pitch": `${pitchRate}` 
            },
          }),
        });
    
        // Create an Audio object from the audioContent and play it
        
        const audioData = await response.json();
        const byteCharacters = atob(audioData.audioContent);
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        
        const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
        const audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        
        // Play the audio
        audio.play();
        
        //Log the audioContent
        console.log('Audio-Data:', audio);}
        catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    });
    
    
    
        // Download the text as audio
    const downloadButton = document.getElementById('download-button');
    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      // Download the text as audio
      const text = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
    
      // Get the selected voice language
      const selectedVoice = document.getElementById('voiceSelect').value;
       
      // Get the selected language code
      const selectedLanguage = document.getElementById('languageSelect').value;
    
      // Get the selected pitch value (0-2)
      const pitchRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pitchSlider').value);
    
      // Get the selected speed value (0.25-4)
      const speakingRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('speedSlider').value);
    
      console.log('Text input:', text);
      console.log('Selected voice:', selectedVoice);
      console.log('Voice pitch:' , pitchRate);
      console.log('Playback speed:', speakingRate);
      console.log('Access Token:', accessToken) 
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
          "input": { 
              "text": `${text}`
              }, // Enclose the text value in quotes
          "voice": { 
              "name": `${selectedVoice}`,
              "languageCode": `${selectedLanguage}`
              }, // Enclose the selectedVoice value in quotes
          "audioConfig": {
              "audioEncoding": "MP3",
              "speakingRate": `${speakingRate}`,
              "pitch": `${pitchRate}` 
            },
        }),
        });
    
        const audioData = await response.json();
        const byteCharacters = atob(audioData.audioContent);
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        
        const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        anchor.download = 'audio.mp3';
        anchor.click();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    });

type here

I tried swapping some of the "const" with "let" but it did not seem to make a difference. I also verified the oAuth2 functionality is working as expected. I also checked to see if the script was accidentally being loaded more than once but it was not. I originally thought maybe it being caused by JS minifying, so I excluded textospeech.js.
It's fixed! I ended up rewriting the parsing section a little differently and now it is working. The updated parsing section is below;
console.log(“BEFORE!”)

// Function to parse access token from URL
function parseAccessTokenFromUrl(url) {
// Get the hash fragment (remove leading #)
const hashFragment = url.split(‘#’)[1];

// Find the index of the ‘&token_type’ parameter
const tokenTypeIndex = hashFragment.indexOf(‘&token_type’);

// Extract the substring containing the access token
const extractedAccessToken = hashFragment.substring(hashFragment.indexOf(‘#access_token=’) + 14, tokenTypeIndex);

// Return the extracted access token (no global variable)
return extractedAccessToken;
}

// Get the current URL
const currentUrl = window.location.href;

// Try parsing the access token
const accessToken = parseAccessTokenFromUrl(currentUrl);

console.log(‘Access Token:’, accessToken);


const url followed by let url..?

Please don't add solutions inside the question. Consider creating an answer

The error is stating that the variable url has been declared multiple times. Declaring multiple identical variables in javascript is restricted.
// Get the current WindowURL.
const url = window.location.href;let url = window.location.href;

To address the error, you can either remove const url or let url.

Instead of creating an answer to point out a typo or a non-reproducible error, close-vote the question and comment as such. Furthermore this was already addressed in the comments

Thank you @DarkBee, I appreciate the response ;)
